# Workflow framework in Python

Tags: python, frameworks, celery, workflow, luigi

I'm trying to create workflow in `Python` that will have the following features below:

> 1. Dynamic scheduling.
> 2. Parallelism - many threads within one process.
> 3. Running a flow same as running a task.
> 4. Works on Windows.

From the knowledge that i get it's seems that 1) & 3) are achievable in many workflow frameworks, but 2) is not that easy. In my research i was mostly looked at `Celery` & `Luigi` frameworks.

- For `Celery` I did found out that 2 could be done using the `--pool` argument, so I would like to know if I can combine the worker & the trigger to the same python module?
- For `Luigi` I would like to know if it's possible to run tasks as multi-threads and not multi-processes?

In addition I would appreciate any suggestions for other `Python` framework that could help me before I start to create my own workflow?

Comment: You should check out the Common Workflow Lanuage and CWLExec which handles everything you said above.

Answer (score 0):

In luigi, it is possible for the tasks themselves to use multithreading, but in luigi each worker will itself be a process, as it can run on a different machine. You could run with just one worker if you have something against having two processes.

Another one to look at is airflow.